# mybatis insert all nextval unique constraint error in @transaction mdoe

Tags: spring, transactions, mybatis

MyBatis 3 spring  - java

I am trying to batch insert and and getting following error when there are more then 1 records. it works perfect with one recrod

I beleive b/c it is in transaction nextval is not generating nextval on each iteration. am i correct any help on that ?

```
nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (LINEAR_UPSELL.SYS_C0016697) violated
```

and my method has Transaction annotation in java file

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

in mapper file following is my insert statement

```
<insert id="insertService" parameterType="java.util.List">
    insert all
    <foreach collection="list" item="ch" index="index" >
    into tva_upselladmin_channel (id, source_id, service_id, name) values  (
        TVA_UPSELLADMIN_CHANNEL_SEQ.nextVal,
        #{ch.sourceId}, 
        #{ch.serviceId}, 
        #{ch.name}
        )
    </foreach>
            SELECT * FROM dual
</insert>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in oracle nextval does not work very well with insert all statement. you have to find work around as following

```
extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select TVA_UPSELLADMIN_CHANNEL_SEQ.nextval - 1 from dual'),'//text()')
```

complete insert as following have no idea with -1 is there.

```
<insert id="insertServiceMappings" parameterType="java.util.List">
    insert all
    <foreach collection="list" item="channel" index="index" >
    into tva_upselladmin_channel (id, source_id, service_id, name) values  (
        extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select TVA_UPSELLADMIN_CHANNEL_SEQ.nextval - 1 from dual'),'//text()'),
        #{channel.sourceId}, 
        #{channel.serviceId}, 
        #{channel.name}
        )
    </foreach>
            SELECT * FROM dual
</insert>
```